# Macro to export MS Word tables to Excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba, export, ms-word

I have a word document with many tables. Does anyone know how to write a macro to export such tables to different Excel sheets?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Answer taken from: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=36875

Here is some code that reads a table from Word into the active worksheet of Excel. It prompts you for the word document as well as the table number if Word contains more than one table.

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    If TableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
        TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If
    With .tables(TableNo)
        'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
        For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
            Next iCol
        Next iRow
    End With
End With

Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

This macro should be inserted into Excel (not Word) and put into a standard macro module rather than into the worksheet or workbook event code modules. To do this, go to the VBA (keyboard Alt-TMV), insert a macro module (Alt-IM), and paste the code into the code pane. Run the macro from the Excel interface as you would any other (Alt-TMM).

If your document contains many tables, as would be the case if your 100+ page table is actually a separate table on each page, this code could easily be modified to read all the tables. But for now I am hoping it is all one continuous table and will not require any modification.

---

Keep Excelling.

Damon

VBAexpert Excel Consulting
(My other life: http://damonostrander.com )

Comment: Thanks for the code. I think I can modify your code to read all tables, but how I create a different excel sheet for each table?

Comment: These source do not keep the text formatting of the original Word tables. Does it exist any solution?

Comment: If the code throws an error while parsing the table, try putting this code on a new line after "With wdDoc" line: "On Error Resume Next". This basically says that if a cell throws a recoverable error, the code execution will not stop but resumes execution to next cell.

Comment: This code imports content from Word into a running Excel sheet.  Is anyone aware of an example that exports the table contents from a running Word document to an Excel sheet?

Comment: BTW, since this post is 10+ years old, if you stumbled upon this beautiful solution, you can change the .doc to .docx to open the modern word document file extension.

Answer (score 20):

I changed [this one](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=36875) with an addition to loop through all tables (starting from the chosen table):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If

    resultRow = 4

    For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
        With .tables(tableStart)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                Next iCol
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next iRow
        End With
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next tableStart
End With

End Sub
```

Next trick: working out how to extract a table within a table from Word... and do I really want to?

TC

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to change For tableStart = 1 To tableTot to For tableStart = tableNo To tableTot so it starts where you told it to. Also did a modification to have each table stored in separated excel workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much Damon and @Tim

I modified it to open docx files, moved a worksheet clear line after checking for escape by user.

Here is the final code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer      'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long            'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer         'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If

    resultRow = 4

    For tableStart = tableNo To tableTot
        With .tables(tableStart)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                Next iCol
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next iRow
        End With
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next tableStart
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This section of code is the one that loops through each table and copies it to excel. Perhaps you could create a worksheet object that dynamically updates the worksheet you are referring to using the table number as a counter.

```
With .tables(TableNo)
'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
Next iCol
Next iRow
End With
End With
```