# Export data from a series of Microsoft Word forms to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-word

At work, we have asked our clients to fill out a questionnaire; the format we sent it to them in is MS Word forms.  To make matters even more complicated, a lot of the data is entered via tickboxes, so a straight copy-paste of the field copies only the labels, not which the client selected.

So now, when we want to get data out of it?  Not so easy.

A sample screenshot of the blank survey:

[image]

It's a Microsoft Word table.  Note that "b) Answer" can be either a checkbox or a free text field, depending on the question.

I would like to extract the information from the Word docs into something more usable, ideally without manually copy-pasting every individual value.  Problem is, I don't know what's possible.  This is the sort of thing I could probably do fairly easily in MS Excel, but adding it as Word makes it more complicated.

Probably the eventual table will have roughly this structure:

```
Client | Category | Question No. | Question Text | Answer | Comment | Compliance
```

Tools I have available to me: Word, Excel, Access, and SQL Server Management Studio.  It will likely be sent to the database eventually, but getting it as far as Access/Excel is sufficient midstep if that's possible.

Can this be done in any even somewhat automated fashion?  Or am I stuck reentering the data from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using a modified version of the scripts offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465212/macro-to-export-ms-word-tables-to-excel-sheets) - most notably Tim's answer that loops through all tables in the document.  To handle the checkboxes, I swapped the copy line for the function from [this page](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showpost.php?p=280417&postcount=8), which turns checked and unchecked checkboxes into "true"s and "false"s respectively.