# how to extract a table , where table name contains the given sub string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a word document with many tables. 
I have used the below macro to export the tables to an excel file.
[Macro to export MS Word tables to Excel sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465212/macro-to-export-ms-word-tables-to-excel-sheets)

that was so helpful really. and I am very much thankful.

but the issue , I face is my job is not done completely.

As such I have just started learning the VBA , 
I am not able to know , how to do the below task.

- i have a word document which Appx contains , 20 tables.
  and I have to extract only one table , where , the table name contains a fixed sub string.

Ex :

If the word document has 3 tables with names
"Table 1 : table with gender and salary" 
"Table 2 : table with salary info"
"Table 3 : table with name , age , gender and salary "

if i run the above macro , i get all the tables to my Excel doc successfully.
but my need is , only to get the Table with name.

"table with name , age , gender and salary"

please suggest me.

Really thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you entering the correct table number in the input box?

This line restricts the import to just that specific table:

```
TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
"Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
```

Comment: The script is able to , extract all the tables in the given word document. the digit  1 , is used to start the default extraction from 1st table in teh word document.

Comment: i Require the "table name to be filtered with the given sub string"

Comment: For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
       found_t = 0
      found_t = WorksheetFunction.FindB("Record Field Data Types", .tables(tableStart), 1)
       
     If found_t Then

Comment: I could able to do it By adding teh above logic.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the some lines as per your requirement ,please check it and let me know

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As string 
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
If TableNo = 0 Then
MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
"Enter table name of table to import", "Import Word Table", "table with name , age , gender and salary")
End If
With .tables(TableNo)
'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
Next iCol
Next iRow
End With
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have u tried the above code. ? ..It will ask you the table name instead of table number ..