# Copy table from Word then paste to Excel using VB.NET

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, ms-word

I'm copying a table from Word then pasting the copied table in an Excel file:

```
tbl.Range.Copy()
oSheet.Activate()
rng = oSheet.Range("A1")
rng.Activate()

rng.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll)
```

But when I do this, the table is pasted as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer which explains how to export MS Word tables to Excel sheets.  It may provide you with the way forward....

[Macro to export MS Word tables to Excel sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465212/macro-to-export-ms-word-tables-to-excel-sheets)

Comment: Thanks Sam but is there anything non-macro? so that I don't have to create a storage file for it?

Comment: Do you mean an assembly?  Like an EXE?  You could transpose that code to VB.NET and use use the Office interop libraries to perform the same actions that are available in VBA....