# How to iterate through word table with unequal rows and columns with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to import a Word table in Excel using VBA. I have some code but I am having a problem iterating through the table as it has unequal rows and columns.

Here's my code so far:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
    
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdTable As Object
    Dim Word_Document_Name As Variant
    Dim TableNo As Integer
    Dim TableIndex As Integer    

    Word_Document_Name = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files,*.doc;*.docx", , "Browse for Word File")

    If Word_Document_Name = False Then Exit Sub 'In case user hit the cancel button

    Set wdDoc = GetObject(Word_Document_Name) 'open Word file (Step takes time to open Word Document and inspect)

    With wdDoc

    TableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count

    If TableNo = 0 Then MsgBox "This document contains no tables": Exit Sub

    For TableIndex = 1 To TableNo

            With .Tables(TableIndex)

                For TableRow = 1 To .Rows.Count

                 < SOME CODE HERE TO FIND NO. OF COLUMNS IN EACH ROW>

                Next                

            End With
            Next TableIndex
    End With
End Sub
```

How can I traverse through the unequal table and get each of its cells content?

Comment: That's difficult to answer without first explaining how you want to deal with the unequal rows/columns.

Comment: So basically, whatever number of rows or columns there are, I just want to iterate through all the cells and get their values.

Comment: In that case take a look at these related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808852/transforming-word-tables-into-excel-array/33809950#33809950  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111444/copying-tables-from-word-to-excel-vba/41136264#41136264

Comment: For both of those, they're using Rows.count and Columns.count. They wouldn't work here since they both give  the maximum number of columns and rows of a table. I get an error if I iterate through for e.g. row 1 with only two columns when Columns.count actually gives me a value of 4.

Comment: In Word VBA you can iterate through the cells collection of the Table.Range to get each cell in  turn.  However I think this is an occasion where cutting from Word and pasting in Excel is the simplest solution. After pasting, you can get the range of the pasted table as the Excel selection range.  There will be two options for the paste, one to use the same layout as word (which results in merged cells in Excel), or to use Excel layout which puts the content of merged Word cells in the top left corner of the Excel cells representing the merged range but doesn't merge any Excel cells.

Comment: @user10614471 - sorry my mistake - see my code example below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can loop over rows and cells even when the number of cells may vary from row to row:

```
Dim t As Table, r As Long, c As Long, rw As Row
Set t = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

For r = 1 To t.Rows.Count
    Set rw = t.Rows(r)
    For c = 1 To rw.Cells.Count
        Debug.Print "In row " & r & " cell " & c
    Next c
Next r
```

Comment: That code won't work where there are vertically-merged cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try something based on the following code:

```
Dim i As Long, wdRng As Object
With wdDoc.Tables(1).Range
  For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
    With .Cells(i)
      Set wdRng = .Range
      wdRng.End = wdRng.End - 1
      MsgBox "Row: " & .RowIndex & vbTab & "Col: " & .ColumnIndex & vbCr & "Text: " & vbTab & wdRng.Text
    End With
  Next
End With
```

Answer (score -1):

I've not been able to find an option that doesn't rely on some sort of error handling. Resume Next should be sufficient for most tasks.

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim tbl As Table
Dim curCell As Cell

Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

On Error Resume Next

For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.count

    For c = 1 To tbl.Columns.count

        Set curCell = tbl.Cell(r, c)
        Debug.Print curCell.Range.text
    Next
Next

On Error GoTo 0
```