# VBA Import page number of Word table into Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, ms-word

In my Word document I have multiple tables which are in different pages.
I need to import the table inside Excel which has already been done with the sample code I have found from [Macro to export MS Word tables to Excel sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465212/macro-to-export-ms-word-tables-to-excel-sheets).

However I intend to import the page number of the table (in Word) into Excel and set it as the Sheet Name but I am unable to find anything at all in the Internet after hours of searching.

How do I import the page number of the table in Word into Excel?

I know that to set it as the Sheet Name we use the command

```
Activesheet.Name="insert_page_number"
```

but how do we import the page number of the table that we imported from Word into Excel?

Comment: this may help: [`Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820800.aspx) where `Selection` would be the expression for the table.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman that only works in Word. How would that be able to transfer that data into Excel? Could you share with me how? Thank you :)

Comment: Assign the page number to a variable when grabbing the table from word, then pass the variable into `ActiveSheet.Name`. For example `With .tables(TableNo) | lPage = .Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) ..` (bar equals line break ... and `Dim lPage as Long` ... Then `ActiveSheet.Name = lPage`

Comment: Followup on what @ScottHoltzman suggested... modify that a bit `oWordApp.Selection.Information(3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the page number using `Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)`. In the sample that you link to, this would look as follows:

```
Dim pageNumber as Integer
Dim wdRange as Range
With .tables(TableNo)
    'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
    For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
        Next iCol
    Next iRow

    ' get the page number of the first paragraph in the table
    pageNumber = .Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)

    ' write the page number below the table
    Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = "Page " & pageNumber
End With
```

Comment: Hi @Dirk when I tried to compile the code, it showed me the error that Variable Not Defined when it came to wdActiveEndPageNumber and this was because that property only existed in Word but not in Excel. How can we solve this problem? Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Thats fine, but if the first row of the table breaks across a page, the `paragraphs` property would mean that the `wdActiveEndPageNumber` would be the page that the *paragraph* ends on. It would be better to do `.Range.Characters(1).Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)`, as this will return the page number of the first character present in the table.

Comment: @AndrewWynn would this mean that pageNumber = .Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters(1).Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) OR that pageNumber = .Range.Characters(1).Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)?

Comment: @NewLearner, the enum is only defined in word, so you can either add a reference to the word object model, or you can just use const = 3, as in:
`.Range.Characters(1).Information(3)`

Comment: @NewLearner, the whole line would be `pageNumber = .Range.Characters(1).Information(3)`

Comment: @AndrewWynn Thank you for your help! I understood that! But sorry to trouble you again, the wdActiveEndPageNumber does not seem to be a recognised property in Excel and keeps giving me errors in compiling. How do I make it "recognised" in a way?

Comment: @NewLearner I don't mean to nitpick terminology, (your name is NewLearner) but the `Information` property requires a `Long`, and to make things easy, the designers of VBA made several Enumerated text strings (`Enums`) that evaluate into `Long`s. in this case, `wdActivePageNumber` == `3`, so you can just use the number 3 if you want. The enums in word dont work in other office applications, but if you go the VBA editor, then to Tools >  References and tick the box for `Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library` (your version may differ), you should be able to use the word enums in Excel.

Comment: @AndrewWynn thank you for clarifying that and guiding the way for me. The tip on activating the Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library was especially useful. There are actually many types of object libraries over there and just a question should I wish to enable macros of any office apps to recognise that of others do i enable all the object libraries too? Thank you for teaching me this fact! Have a good afternoon

Comment: @NewLearner - Early Binding (Referencing the Application Object Library in Tools > References) allows you to use the constant names like `wdActivePageNumber`. Late Binding, which you did in your code with `Dim Word as Object` does not allow for these constants since the Object is a general variable and is not set to the actually Word (or other) Application, as in Early Binding, where `Dim Word as Word.Application` .. read more [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245115)