# Copy selection of Word tables to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, import, ms-word

I have modified the code from [Macro to export MS Word tables to Excel sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465212/macro-to-export-ms-word-tables-to-excel-sheets/9406983#9406983) to copy a sequential interval of tables (e.g. 1 to 4) instead of copying all tables, as in the original code.

But I cannot figure out how to copy a selection of tables in the Word document (e.g. tables 1, 3, 7, 8).

Help to tweak the relevant section of code much appreciated!

```
        'For tableStart = 1 To tableTo '<- copies all tables
        For tableStart = 1 To 4 '<- copies sequential interval of tables

            With .tables(tableStart)
                .Range.Copy
                Target.Activate
                Target.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                'ActiveSheet.Paste <- pastes with formatting

                Set Target = Target.Offset(.Rows.Count + 2, 0)
            End With

        Next tableStart
```

The entire macro is:

```
Sub ImportWordTables()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim arrFileList As Variant, FileName As Variant
    Dim tableNo As Integer    'table number in Word
    Dim tableStart As Integer
    Dim tableTot As Integer
    Dim Target As Range

    On Error Resume Next 

    arrFileList = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc; *.docx),*.doc;*.docx", 2, _
                                              "Browse for file containing table to be imported", , True)

    If Not IsArray(arrFileList) Then Exit Sub         '<-user cancelled import file browser

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = False

    Range("A:AZ").ClearContents
    Set Target = Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A1") 

    For Each FileName In arrFileList
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)

        With WordDoc
            tableNo = WordDoc.tables.Count
            tableTot = WordDoc.tables.Count
            If tableNo = 0 Then
                MsgBox WordDoc.Name & "Contains no tables", vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
            End If
            
            'For tableStart = 1 To tableTo '<- copies all tables
            For tableStart = 1 To 4 '<- copies interval of tables
                With .tables(tableStart)
                    .Range.Copy
                    Target.Activate
                    Target.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                    'ActiveSheet.Paste <- pastes with formatting

                    Set Target = Target.Offset(.Rows.Count + 2, 0)
                End With
            Next tableStart

            .Close False
        End With

    Next FileName

    WordApp.Quit

    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, but input box and memory capacity issue still to be fixed.

Replace `With .tables(tableIndex)` section in my first example above with the following:

```
'For array
Dim tables() As Variant
Dim tableCounter As Long

tables = Array(1, 3, 7)  '<- define array manually here

For tableCounter = LBound(tables) To UBound(tables)
    With .tables(tables(tableCounter))
        .Range.Copy
       
        Target.Activate
        'Target.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False '<- gives RAM capacity problems!
        ActiveSheet.Paste '<- pastes with formatting

        Set Target = Target.Offset(.Rows.Count + 2, 0)
    End With
    
Next tableCounter
```

Answer (score 1):

You could supply the list of tables as an array.  I added this to the restructured code below.  You provide a variant containing an  array of the table numbers you want to copy to the ImportWordTables sub.  I'll leave it to you to modify the code by making the parameter optional so that you either copy all tables or the tables in the list.

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum TableImportError

    NoTables
    UnexpectedIndex

End Enum


Public Sub ImportWordTables(ByVal ipTableList As Variant)
    
    Dim arrFileList As Variant
    If Not TryGetFileNameList(arrFileList) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = False

    ' the range should be qualified by the relevant wb/ws
    Range("A:AZ").ClearContents
    
    Dim FileName As Variant
    For Each FileName In arrFileList
    
        Dim WordDoc As Object
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
        
        Dim myReason As TableImportError
        If Not TryImportTables(WordDoc, ipTableList, myReason) Then
        
            Select Case myReason
            
                Case TableImportError.NoTables
                
                    MsgBox WordDoc.Name & "Contains no tables", vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
                    
                Case TableImportError.UnexpectedIndex
                
                    MsgBox WordDoc.Name & "Unexpected index", vbExclamation, "The table indexes exceed the total table count.  No tables copies"
                
            End Select
        
        End If
        
    Next FileName

    WordApp.Quit

    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
    
End Sub


Private Function TryGetFileNameList(ByRef opFileList As Variant) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    opFileList = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc; *.docx),*.doc;*.docx", 2, _
                                              "Browse for file containing table to be imported", , True)
    On Error GoTo 0
    TryGetFileNameList = IsArray(opFileList)
    
End Function


Private Function TryImportTables(ByRef ipDoc As Word.Document, ByVal ipTableList As Variant, ByRef opReason As TableImportError) As Boolean

    TryImportTables = False
    
    If ipDoc.Tables.Count = 0 Then
    
        opReason = TableImportError.NoTables
        Exit Function
    
    End If
    
    Dim myTable As Variant
    For Each myTable In ipTableList
    
        If myTable > ipDoc.Tables.Count Then
        
            opReason = TableImportError.UnexpectedIndex
            Exit Function
            
        End If
        
    Next
        
    For Each myTable In ipTableList
    
        With ipDoc.Tables.Item(myTable)
          
            .Range.Copy
            ' replaced Target by worksheet refernce
            ' ideally this item should be passed as a parameter
            ' or second best defined as a module level variable.
            '
            ' worksheets should be qualified by the relevant wb
            With Worksheets("MySheet")
            
                .Activate
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                Set .Range("A1") = .Range("A1").Offset(.Rows.Count + 2, 0)
                '.Paste
                
            End With
                
        End With
        
    Next
    
    TryImportTables = True

End Function
```

The code above compiles and doesn't give any unexpected Code Inspection warning by the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA.  However as its a radical restructuring I can't guarantee it will work exactly as you previous code so please do check if you decide to use it.

Comment: Thank you @freeflow. Sorry, unfortunately I really don't understand this! :-( An array was what I expected I could use to replace `tableStart`, but your code opens a dialog box for me to open yet another macro, so I don't really see the point of that.

Comment: Then there is something wrong.  It works fine on my PC.  e.g. 'ImportWordTables array(1,3,6,9")'.  I also realised that for TryImportTables you might need to change ipDoc as 'Word.Document' to 'ipDoc as Object' if you don't have a reference to WOrd.

Comment: Hi @freeflow - maybe I have installed your code incorrectly (I have copied it exactly)? The reason it is opening the Macro dialog is that no macro is registered in the workbook at all. So when I run the code in the editor, it looks for a macro and opens the Macro dialog. Any suggestions? The ref to Word is installed.

Comment: Try placing the code in a Module.  That's where I wrote it.  As its generic code it should not sit in a worksheet code area.

Comment: Have tried both module and worksheet - also tried on a second PC. Same result. :-(

Comment: Then I'm stuck. I rarely use Excel, most of my VBA ing is in Word.  However, if you look at the code you can take the principles and implement them in your own code.

Comment: Also `Compile Error: User-defined type not defined` at `Private Function TryImportTables(ByRef ipDoc As Word.Document, ByVal ipTableList As Variant, ByRef opReason As TableImportError) As Boolean`

Comment: As I said in my comment, you may have to replace Word.Document by Object if you don't have a reference for Word.

Answer (score 1):

Set this code of yours as a Function that you call from the Main Sub with the a TableIndex

```
        With .tables(tableIndex)
            .Range.Copy
            Target.Activate
            Target.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
            'ActiveSheet.Paste <- pastes with formatting

            Set Target = Target.Offset(.Rows.Count + 2, 0)
        End With
```

Set the tableIndex variable as a Random number assigned from the collection of tables in the Word document. You'll have to decide how many times you will iterate thru the code so you get the random sample size you want but the basic code might look like this:

```
Sub ReturnRandomNumber()
    Dim TableIndex As Integer
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Randomize
    TableIndex = Int((WordDoc.Tables.Count * Rnd) + 1)
    CopyRandomTable WordDoc, TableIndex
End Sub
Function CopyRandomTable(ByRef WordDoc As Word.Document, ByRef TableIndex As Integer)
    With WordDoc.Tables(TableIndex)
        .Range.Copy
        Target.Activate
        Target.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        'ActiveSheet.Paste <- pastes with formatting

        Set Target = Target.Offset(.rows.Count + 2, 0)
    End With
End Function
```

The RND function might also return the same table index so you should think about how you might want to deal with that ... like possibly setting up an array of table indexes already used and then act accordingly.

For more information about Randomize and the RND function here is a [Microsoft Article on the RND Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function).

Comment: Thanks @Rich Michaels - I think I have used the word "random" foolishly! I meant like an array I can change in the macro from time to time. Today array(1,3,5) - tomorrow array(2,9,10), etc.

Comment: @cdfj Instead of having to go into the macro to simply change table index values, how about adding an InputBox method and you type in the random tables you want? If you type 1,3,7 into the InputBox then you can use the Split method to parse the string and pass the table indexes to the Function I proposed.

Comment: Thanks again @Rich Michaels - you have raised the bar way above my height, but I will try to meet the challenge!